# R store multiple vectors from unformated text files

Tags: r

I have files that are automatically generated and I cannot change the format. I would like to be able to store the data in an appropriate R format. They go as such:

```
File: /path/to/file


Start Date: 07/05/16
Subject: 0
Start Time: 10:01:09
Name: FooBar
K:       0.000
O:       0.000
A: 
    0:       91.600       65.000      238.000       31.000       24.000
    5:        7.000    22162.000       78.000       10.000    20000.000
   10:       55.000        0.000        2.000        6.000       53.000
B:
    0:        0.000        2.000        1.000        1.000        1.000
    5:        1.000        1.000        1.000        1.000        1.000

[...] # Goes all the way to Z
Start Date: 07/05/16
Subject: 8
Start Time: 10:11:09
Name: JohnDoe
K:       0.000
O:       0.000
A:
    0:       91.600       65.000      238.000       31.000       24.000
[...] # Goes all the way to Z
```

I opened the file using `readLines`, therefore line are each a long character. Each file contains multiple sessions that are identified by date, name, subject and time. Each session contains multiple numeric variables that represent the alphabet (`LETTERS`). For example, in the first session (FooBar), K could be represented as `c(0.000)` and B as

```
c(0.000,2.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000,1.000)
```

The first rows (File, Start Date, Start Time, Name) are information on the sessions which I was able to save in that dataframe:

```
#Sessions data.frame
structure(list(`Start Date` = c("07/05/16", "07/05/16"), Subject = c("0", "8"), `Start Time` = c("10:01:09", 
"10:11:09"), Name = c("FooBar", 
"JohnDoe"
)), .Names = c("Start Date", "Subject", "Start Time", "name"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

They are two things I am struggling with

1. How can I save the variables (A-Z) as numeric vectors?
2. How can I structure these numeric vectors so that it will be easy to retrieve them for each session?

I had in mind a combination of `apply`, `startsWith` and `scan` but I can't figure the best way to structure my data.

Comment: Would you be open for a solution not using R ? I think awk could do a good job at processing the file and outputting something more usable for R.

Comment: @Tensibai Unfortunately we can only use an R solution in our environment. However, I can work with any R package if necessary.

Comment: Then good luck, it would be quite easy to turn this into a csv with awk, not that easy in R only. (I'd be curious about the why awk can't be used that said, even calling it from R `system2` at worst)

Comment: @Tensibai I am not allowed to do system calls in my environment

Comment: I may give it a try, but will depend on how much time I can free up.

Comment: @Tensibai It would be much appreciated. I thought that sometime like creating a vector for each `LETTERS` and session. Then, checking if each lines `startsWith` any of the `LETTERS` and append the line's data to the appropriate letter vector. Then, something like `scan` could parse the characters vectors into numeric vectors.

Comment: Yep something I'm this idea. And creating a data.frame from those vectors, main problem will be to 'link' A,B,C.. to the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you're after but that's the best I can think of with a drawback, there's code growing vector in the loop because we can't really guess how long the vector will be in advance.
We can't create a data.frame because A,B, etc. vectors are not of the same lenghts (it would need to pad them with NA, but it sounds not interesting at all)

```
sessions <- list()
sd <- subject <- st <- sname <- cvec <- ""
lines = readLines("c:/tmp/test.txt")
cases <- c("Start Date:", "Subject:", "Start Time:", "Name:", LETTERS, " ")
lnames <- c("SDate", "Subject", "STime", "Name", LETTERS)
for (l in lines) { # loop on line
  if (nchar(l) < 2) # skip lines with less than 1 char ( A: )
    next
  v <- lnames[min(which(startsWith(l, cases)))] # Get the "field" name
  fields <- strsplit(l, " ")[[1]]
  # Here comes the fun, for each case store the value or update a vector
  if (is.na(v)) { # No field, it's a line of the form "spaces digit: space separated values"
    vals <- fields[nchar(fields) > 1]
    sessions[[sname]][[cvec]] <-
      c(sessions[[sname]][[cvec]], as.integer(vals[-1])) # We just concatenate with previous value for this letter
  }
  else if (v == "SDate")
    sd <- fields[3]
  else if (v == "Subject")
    subject = fields[2]
  else if (v == "STime")
    st <- fields[3]
  else if (v == "Name") {
    sname <- fields[2]
    # Create a new session list entry
    sessions[[sname]] = list(
      "SDate" = sd,
      "STime" = st,
      "Subject" = as.numeric(subject)
    )
  }
  else if (any(v %in% LETTERS)) { # Swich letter vector, use on line value if there's some
    cvec <- v
    sessions[[sname]][[cvec]] <- vector("numeric")
    if (length(fields) > 1) {
      vals <- fields[-1]
      sessions[[sname]][[cvec]] <- as.numeric(vals[nchar(vals) > 1])
    }
  }
}
```

This create a list of list:

```
> str(sessions)
List of 2
 $ FooBar :List of 7
  ..$ SDate  : chr "07/05/16"
  ..$ STime  : chr "10:01:09"
  ..$ Subject: num 0
  ..$ K      : num 0
  ..$ O      : num 0
  ..$ A      : num [1:15] 91 65 238 31 24 ...
  ..$ B      : num [1:10] 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ JohnDoe:List of 7
  ..$ SDate  : chr "07/05/16"
  ..$ STime  : chr "10:11:09"
  ..$ Subject: num 8
  ..$ K      : num 0
  ..$ O      : num 0
  ..$ A      : num [1:15] 91 65 238 31 24 ...
  ..$ B      : num [1:10] 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This gives for session "FooBar":

```
sessions$FooBar
$SDate
[1] "07/05/16"

$STime
[1] "10:01:09"

$Subject
[1] 0

$K
[1] 0

$O
[1] 0

$A
 [1]    91    65   238    31    24     7 22162    78    10 20000    55     0     2     6    53

$B
 [1] 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```